# Bootstrap-Select opens option under the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed size div. suppose 50px. Inside that I have a drop down. I've used **bootstrap select** to make it searchable.

```
<div style="height=40px;width:200%; overflow-x:scroll;" id="hugewidth">
  <select id="ss">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>1</option>
  </select>
  <br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Now problem is when I open the dropdown , options goes under the `hugewidth` div. I want the dropdown to open above that div. See the JSFiddle that might clear the problem.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9hyD/)

See!! It goes under the scrollbar. Can anyone please help me with this??
I want the dropdown option div to go over the scrollbar. If not possible, then is there any way to adjust the div height according to the dropdown option size while open and close? **Dropdown options are dynamic.**

One more thing. Is it possible to stop a dropdown to open upwards? Example: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9hyD/1/)

Comment: Why are you giving `overflow-x:scroll;` in div

Comment: Cause I needed to. This is an example code. Actual web app need the huge div and to be able to scroll horizontally. @DurgeshChaudhary

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can add:

```
data-container="body"
```

to select element. Or another element to show dropdown over there. See it:
http://jsfiddle.net/IceManSpy/Y9hyD/2/

demo in documentation: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

Comment: Awesome bro, Exactly the way I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yep it worked. Also, after doing a quick search, the documentation does mention this. https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

Comment: I spent 3 days for searching this answer

Answer (score 0):

To make all the bootstrap *dropdown* and *select* menus go off of its container and make it behave like it's fixed by its button.

`Bootstrap-select` plugin actually creates a button.dropdown-toggle - and I didn't notice it at first

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.dropdown-toggle').forEach( (e) => {
    e.setAttribute('data-boundary', 'window');
    e.setAttribute('data-container', 'body');
});
```

This also solves overflow visibility issues when adding a dropdown to a `table-responsive`