# Bootstrap select - using data-container="body" breaks functionality

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I was having a problem with the Bootstrap `select` going under another `div`, and find a solution that solved it in the following question:
[Bootstrap-Select opens option under the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603864/bootstrap-select-opens-option-under-the-div)

The solution suggests adding `data-container="body"` to Bootstrap `select`, and it solved this problem but caused side effects on the bootstrap functionality:

1. When the `select` is opened, clicking outside its scope won't close it.
2. When the `select` is opened, clicking on the `select` itself (the original box) won't close it.
3. When trying the functionality described on 1 and 2, the `select` gets almost completely stuck and even clicking on a valid `option` won't close the `select` now.

Without using `data-container="body"` on the `select` none of this happens, but then I have the original problem.
I need help if anyone has an idea what is happening.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've altered a line of code that has solved my problem of select menus not closing once opened.

bootstrap-select.js line 1002.

original code

```
.toggleClass('open', !$this.hasClass('open'))
```

my altered code

```
.toggleClass('open')
```

Someone else may be able to weigh in on this and explain why.