# bootstrap select bug when there are more values and scrolling upwards it shows no search box

Tags: laravel-5.4, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

If there are less values like

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true">
                        <option>Mustard</option>
                        <option>Ketchup</option>
                        <option>Relish</option>
                    </select>
```

[image: Correct view if there are less options]

and it scroll to downwards, it works fine but when there are more value like

```
<select class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-actions-box="true" data-live-search="true">
                            <option>Mustard</option>
                            <option>Ketchup</option>
                            <option>Relish</option>
                            <option>Mustard</option>
                            <option>Ketchup</option>
                            <option>Relish</option> <option>Mustard</option>
                            <option>Ketchup</option>
                            <option>Relish</option> <option>Mustard</option>
                            <option>Ketchup</option>
                            <option>Relish</option>
                        </select>
```

it behaves like this
[image: no search bar]

no searchable or select all or deselect all options are hided

an fix for that?

Comment: it looks like search filed is going behind my header bar

Comment: it looks like something has to do with z-index but i can't figure it out

Comment: this solution resolved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603864/bootstrap-select-opens-option-under-the-div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in documentation if your select element is inside an element with overflow: hidden then it will not be able to scroll if you have many options,

But it also provide solution that You can Append the select menu to a specific element which does not have `overflow:hidden` style, e.g. `data-container='body'` or `data-container=".main-content"`.

**Example:**

```
 <div style="overflow:hidden;">
  <select class="selectpicker" id="no-scroll">
    ...
  </select>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-container="body" id="can-scroll">
    ...
  </select>

 </div>
```

here if your parent or any parent of parent has css as `overflow:hidden` then when you have more elements in select elements then scroll will not work,

as in above example in select element with `id='no-scroll'` scrolling will not work ,

but if you provide `data-container='body'` or any div class like `data-container='.class-with-overflow-visible-property'` which has `overflow:visible` property then it will work,

see in above example in select element with `id='can-scroll'` scrolling will work as expected.

reference : https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#container

Comment: Omg, i've been looking for this solution for a long time, always had a problem with selectpicker + modal windows. Thanks a lot!